# Is Low Search able to search on a Playa field inside a Matrix field?

Tags: matrix, playa

Is there a way to search a Playa field inside a Matrix field?

If not, are there any other alternatives(like using a hook) or is it really not possible?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean you want a keyword search to include the titles of entries selected in a Playa field, which is inside of a Matrix field, and then to return that entry in which that Matrix relationship was made as the result?

Comment: Just a keyword search on relationship playa matrix fields marked as searchable.

Comment: If it's just the title of the child entry you want to search, then that will be searchable by default, as Playa stores that data directly in Matrix/channel fields when set to searchable. But that would give you a hit linking to the parent entry, not the child entry.

Comment: @DerekHogue Ok, I think you are right. Please post your answer so that I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the title of the child entry you want to search, then that will be searchable by default, as Playa stores that data directly in Matrix/channel fields (when they are set to searchable in the field settings).

To clarify, that would give you a search result linking to the parent entry, not the child entry.